# Particleground animation background not appearing behind text, instead appearing above text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the particleground jquery background for a specific div/section, but when I use the jquery function and accordingly alter the CSS, the particles appear above the text and not behind it, as I wish. I tried changing the z-index to -1, but that does not help either. I want the div to remain as it is but all I want is that the particles appear behind it. Here is the HTML :

```
<div id="particles1">
    <section class="container-fluid action"  style="background-color: #00a1de" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" >
                    <h3  style="color: white"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry <a href="#contact" id="go-to-contact" style="color:">contact us</a>.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS of the code :

```
section.action {
    background-color: #00a1de;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    text-align: center;
}

section.action h3 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    display: inline-block;
}

section.action h3 a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}

section.action h3 a:hover {
    color: #002776;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    section.action h3 {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

and

```
#particles1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 375px;
    position: relative;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    background: #00a1de;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    #particles1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        position: relative;
        background: #00a1de;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
    #particles1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 800px;
        position: relative;
        background: #00a1de;
    }
}
```

And finally here is the javascript I am using :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    particleground(document.getElementById('particles1'), {
        dotColor: '#1b3277',
        lineColor: '#1b3277'
    });
    var intro = document.getElementById('intro');
    intro.style.marginTop = -intro.offsetHeight / 2 + 'px';
}, false);
```

Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: would you be able to provide a jsfiddle of it? so that we can mess around with the demo?

Comment: Here is the fiddle. Though the particles are not appearing despite including the necessary scripts http://jsfiddle.net/m5jtmdkt/

Comment: Help would be appreciated :)

Comment: sorry, i wont be able to help unless i see whats happening ._. im not really good at deciphering code by itself, and the demo doesnt show your issue. i did upvote your question in hopes that someone else would catcha a whiff and take a stab at your issue

Comment: I got the jsfiddle to display the issue -  http://jsfiddle.net/m5jtmdkt/

Comment: it doesnt show on my computer. `test/jquery.particleground.min.js` is probably why cause it points to nothing on my computer. but try adding this: `#particles1 { z-index: 1; }` and `h3 { z-index: 5; }` to where you have those selectors in your css